# Turing an old laptop into a bitcoin miner

Tags: mining-pools, client, mining-hardware, miner-configuration

So I have an old laptop that was passed down to me, and I want to turn it into a bitcoin miner, I don't have any experience with bitcoin mining; its got 2gb of ram and some pentium. it will be running all the time.

Thanks in advance
Holden

Comment: Probably a very bad idea. Not only will it be terribly inefficient at mining. It will also incur a net loss due to electricity cost!

Comment: What you *could* do instead is mine a coin with a PoW that's CPU friendly, such as a Cryptonote coin. You can then sell those for bitcoins on sites like Poloniex, or P2P markets like bitsquare. You may not get a lot, but I believe you can still come out ahead of electricity costs with Monero, as laptops are fairly low in electricity consumption. If you wish to try this, ask another question about it.